# <cmath> hides isnan in <math.h> in C++14 / C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, nan, cmath

I have here a small test app which uses `isnan` from `<math.h>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double d = NAN;

    std::cout << isnan(d) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Build and run under 3 different standards:**

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++98 main.cpp; ./a.out
> 1
>
> $ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp; ./a.out
> 1
>
> $ g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp; ./a.out
> 1
> ```

Now we also include `<cmath>`, and test with both `isnan` and `std::isnan`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double d = NAN;

    std::cout << std::isnan(d) << '\n';
    std::cout << isnan(d) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Build and run:**

***C++98 works***

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++98 main.cpp; ./a.out
> 1
> 1
> ```

***C++11 and C++14 don't, `isnan` is not found.***

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:10:25: error: ‘isnan’ was not declared in this scope
>      std::cout << isnan(d) << '\n';
>                          ^
> main.cpp:10:25: note: suggested alternative:
> In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
> /usr/include/c++/5/cmath:641:5: note:   ‘std::isnan’
>      isnan(_Tp __x)
>      ^
>
> $ g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:10:25: error: ‘isnan’ was not declared in this scope
>      std::cout << isnan(d) << '\n';
>                          ^
> main.cpp:10:25: note: suggested alternative:
> In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
> /usr/include/c++/5/cmath:641:5: note:   ‘std::isnan’
>      isnan(_Tp __x)
>      ^
> ```

Note the order of inclusion is not important. If I include `<cmath>` before `<math.h>` or after, the result is the same.

**Questions**

- Why is `isnan` gone?
- Without having to go back and change old code to compile under the new standard, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is Clang using libc++, or the same libstdc++ that gcc is?

Comment: @ildjarn `ldd` says it's the same (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`). I've edited the question to remove the clang part.

Comment: Weird problem.. What if you swap strings including cmath and math.h? As for me, I'm avoiding usage of c* headers like cmath

Comment: @AntonMalyshev are you asking about order of inclusion? That makes no difference.

Comment: What version of the compilers are you using?  I cannot reproduce with [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79a28e0056232dd1) or [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/393e772c6846ef3c) on coliru.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev can't avoid the usage of the c* headers - this is old code which needs to be built as part of a larger codebase built using newer standards

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm using `g++ 5.4.0`. glibc version is `2.23`

Comment: hmm.  Apparently coliru uses ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.13) 2.15

Comment: @NathanOliver following your comment I tried on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox). It doesn't have `gcc-5.4.0` but it does have `5.3.0` and `6.1.0`, and I can't replicate on either... Very strange!

Comment: Don't use both cmath and math.h...

Comment: It looks like it may be a bug with the library.  [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) fails 4.9.2 through 5.3 but works on 6.1

Comment: @Ven, I'm not. The code in question uses `math.h`. However, I assume some other include is including something which is including something which ultimately includes `cmath`, so both are in scope. Hence the compile failure, and hence me writing this small app to diagnose what is happening

Comment: @NathanOliver that's very interesting! [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org) fails to compile for 5.3, while [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox) works for 5.3.

Comment: Very bizarre.  It will be interesting to see what the cause of this inconsistency is.  Sorry I could only confuse the problem more :)

Comment: @NathanOliver no, thanks for helping confirm I'm not crazy! I'll have a look on bugzilla and see if I can find anything

Comment: @NathanOliver I've run this on Centos gcc-4.9.1 and gcc-5.2.1 and it works on both. Running it on Ubuntu gcc-4.9.3 works, but gcc-5.4.0 doesn't. Given godbolt fails for some, but wandbox doesn't... well, I'm not sure what to think?!

Comment: @SteveLorimer If you do not find something out in a couple days give me a ping and I will place a bounty.  I would really love to know what is going on.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Briefly summarizing the pertinent points, mostly from [Jonathan Wakely's excellent blog post](http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/29/why-cstdlib-is-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/):

- glibc <2.23's `math.h` declares the obsolete X/Open `int isnan(double);` that is incompatible with the C99/C++11 version (`bool isnan(double);`).
- glibc 2.23's `math.h` fixes this by not declaring the `isnan` function in C++11 or later.
- All of them still define an `isnan` macro. `#include <cmath>` nukes that macro as required by the C++ standard.
- GCC 6's libstdc++ provides its own special `math.h` header that declares a `bool isnan(double);` in the global namespace (unless the libc `math.h` declares the obsolete signature) and also nukes the macros as required by the standard.
- Before GCC 6, `#include <math.h>` simply included the header from your libc, so the macro isn't nuked.
- `#include <cmath>` always nukes the macros.

Net result, in C++11 mode:

```
glibc <  2.23, GCC <  6: <math.h> uses the macro; <cmath> uses obsolete signature
glibc >= 2.23, GCC <  6: <math.h> uses the macro; <cmath> results in error
glibc <  2.23, GCC >= 6: <math.h> and <cmath> use obsolete signature
glibc >= 2.23, GCC >= 6: <math.h> and <cmath> use standard signature
```

Comment: @NathanOliver you saw this answer?

Comment: @SteveLorimer I have now.  Thanks T.C. for another great answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you look inside `<cmath>` from GCC, it has this:

```
. . .
#include <math.h>
. . .
#undef isnan
```

That's why the order doesn't matter - whenever you `#include <cmath>`, `<math.h>` is auto-included and its contents is (partially) nuked.

Attempting to include it again will have no effect because of `#ifndef _MATH_H`.

---

Now, what does the standard have to say about this behavior?

[[depr.c.headers]](http://eel.is/c++draft/depr.c.headers):

> ... every C header, each
>   of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed
>   in the standard library namespace by the corresponding c*name* header is
>   placed within the global namespace scope. It is unspecified whether
>   these names are first declared or defined within namespace scope
>   ([basic.scope.namespace]) of the namespace `std` and are then injected
>   into the global namespace scope by explicit *using-declarations*
>   ([namespace.udecl]).
>
> [ Example: The header `<cstdlib>` assuredly provides its declarations
>   and definitions within the namespace `std`. It ***may*** also provide these
>   names within the global namespace. The header `<stdlib.h>` assuredly
>   provides the same declarations and definitions within the global
>   namespace, much as in the C Standard. It may also provide these names
>   within the namespace `std`.  — end example ]

So it's OK that `<cmath>` does not provide `isnan` in the global namespace.

But it's a gray area what should happen when *both* are included in one compilation unit, although one could argue that the statement above *implies* that both versions must interoperate, in which case it would be a bug in GCC/libstdc++ (some versions).

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the functions inside `math.h` are actually macros. Since this is not idiomatic c++ the header `cmath` contains following code:

```
    ...
    #undef isinf
    #undef isnan
    #undef isnormal
    ...
```

And implements then all those undefined macros as function in the `namespace std`. This is at least true for gcc 6.1.1. That's why your compiler can't find `isnan`.

Comment: I can compile both `std::isnan` and `isnan` on `gcc-6.1` on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/eTRVmF)

Comment: If it were problem with undef, the order of including would matter, but it doesn't matter

Comment: @AntonMalyshev : Why would the order matter? `cmath` will almost always include `math.h`, which will have a header guard – it will always be included once, and only once.