# How to solve "'isnan' was not declared in this scope" without upgrading GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc

I am using GCC 5.4 and getting `'isnan' was not declared in this scope` error.
I found [<cmath> hides isnan in <math.h> in C++14 / C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130040/cmath-hides-isnan-in-math-h-in-c14-c11).

but I have to keep the GCC version, without modifying the source which uses `isnan`, and C++14 standard. so I want to know any trick to solve it.

for example: define isnan=std::isnan as compile -D argument?

Comment: Consider compiling [GCC 10](http://gcc.gnu.org/) from source code, or try using the [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) C++ compiler

Comment: Hi @BasileStarynkevitch my source code is for compiling so old low-leve driver which require GCC version >= 5.

Comment: Discuss with your manager the opportunity to upgrade your GCC compiler. Upgrade to GCC 10 and invoke it as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` at least

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ok, I see, Thank you.

Comment: `without modifying the source which uses isnan, and C++14 standard.` is that really no option? It is not uncommon for package managers to include patch files for the source files as a quick fix if the upstream source code isn't fully compatible with the distribution. So creating a diff file to patch in the corresponding headers in the build process looks like a durable option. (It for sure might be a license problem depending one what exactly you do)